# Transform nested JSON arrays into an array of JSON objects

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following set of variable JSON data where the first row is the list of element names and the other rows represent the list of element values:

```
[
  [
    "category",
    "author",
    "title",
    "price"
  ],
  [
    "reference",
    "Nigel Rees",
    "Sayings of the Century",
    "8.95"
  ],
  [
    "fiction",
    "Evelyn Waugh",
    "Sword of Honour",
    "12.99"
  ],
  [
    "fiction",
    "Herman Melville",
    "Moby Dick",
    "8.99"
  ],
  [
    "fiction",
    "J. R. R. Tolkien",
    "The Lord of the Rings",
    "22.99"
  ]
]
```

I want to build the following type of JSON object from the data:

```
{
  "book": [
    {
      "category": "reference",
      "author": "Nigel Rees",
      "title": "Sayings of the Century",
      "price": 8.95
    },
    {
      "category": "fiction",
      "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
      "title": "Sword of Honour",
      "price": 12.99
    },
    {
      "category": "fiction",
      "author": "Herman Melville",
      "title": "Moby Dick",
      "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
      "price": 8.99
    },
    {
      "category": "fiction",
      "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
      "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
      "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
      "price": 22.99
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I build my JSON object which should be identical to the above.  I don't see any direct support for doing this using JSON.NET APIs.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks more like some sort of csv data.

Comment: Please share what you have tried. This is not a code service site. Iterate each line, parse it to the corresponding object, add to a result collection and then convert to JSON. Please refer to [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to post a good question

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea to get you on the right track.

```
        JObject obj = new JObject();
        var child = new JArray();

        var child2 = new JObject();
        child2.Add("category", "references");
        child.Add(child2);

        obj.Add("book", child);

        var result = obj.ToString();
```

I won't do the string parsing for you, i think you should be able to handle that.

The piece of code I've given produces the following JSON:

```
               {
                "book": [
                  {
                      "category": "references"
                    }
                  ]
                }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this transformation using Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/linqtojson.htm) API:

```
JArray array = JArray.Parse(origJson);

string[] keys = array.First().Select(t => t.ToString()).ToArray();

JArray array2 = 
    new JArray(array.Skip(1).Select(a => 
        new JObject(a.Select((t, i) => 
            new JProperty(keys[i], t)
        ))
    ));

JObject obj = new JObject(new JProperty("book", array2));

string finalJson = obj.ToString();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kMyHOe